# Prestashop overloading backoffice navigation nav.tpl

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to overriding navigation template file:

```
/admin/themes/template/nav.tpl
```

I put code in

```
/my_module_dir/override/controller/admin/template/nav.tpl
```

code:

```
{extends file="nav.tpl"}
<h1>TEST</h1>
```

I clear cache and restart module but code not showing. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only overide controller templates and eventually a helper templates. nav.tpl is just included in header.tpl without using override functionality.

Comment: Is there a hook inside backoffice navigation menu, I need to add module link in nav ul list

Comment: If you need to add tab, you have class "Tab" for that.